# How to split up contours detected in OpenCV?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, contour

I'm currently trying to find contours of grains in a sample mapping after applying a threshold to it. In the picture you can see that if those grains are adjacent to each other very closely they are detected as a single contour. Therefore I am trying to split the contours at their thinnest section. My main problem however is that I don't wknow how to work with the numpy array to actually split the contour so that the result is two arrays.
(I cannot include pictues because of reputation, I'm a fresh user)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYZgx.jpg

I tried to make a function that I can pass the contours found by cv2.findContours() to split them up using some criteria. I compare distances to each other and filter it up a little with two factors. Basically I get the two indices of the two point were the split should occur (a and b). Now i wish to move the points in between to a new contour (array?) and delete those points from the old. Then add both to a new list or array which equals the cv2.findContour() in result. I guess my problem is mostly not understanding the conecpt of the numpy-type (array).

```
def split(contours, ki = 0.25, ks = 0.25):
contours_new = []
for contour in contours:
    dists = []
    count = len(contour)
    for i in range(0,count-1,1):
        for j in range(i+1,count-1,1):
            idist = j - i  # "index-distance", to exclude neighboring points
            if idist > ki*count:
                p1 = contour[i][0]
                p2 = contour[j][0]
                d = dist(p1,p2) #calculates the distance between two points using simple pythagoras
                if d <= fit_size(contour)*ks:
                    dists.append([d, i, j])
                    #print('{}-{}: {}'.format(i,j,d))
    #print(dists)
    if len(dists) > 0:
        dists = sorted(dists, key=lambda a: a[0])
        a = dists[0][1] #first point
        b = dists[0][2] # second point, split bewteen these!
        old = contour
        new = old[a:b] # ????????????
        old = np.delete(old,range(a,b,1)) # ????????????
        # i = 0
        # new = []
        # while a < (b - i):
        #     new.append(old.pop(a))
        #     i = i + 1
        contours_new.append(old)
        contours_new.append(new)
    else:
        contours_new.append(contour)

print('OLD: {} - NEW: {}'.format(len(contours),len(contours_new)))
return contours_new
```

Passing the result to my drawing function (which perfectly draws the contours found by cv2.findContours()), does result in an error:

error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours'

Comment: means input edge image contains no image. do a quick image check to verify that the edge has non zero data

Answer (score 1):

I have modified my code and it seems to work now:

```
    if len(dists) > 0:
        dists = sorted(dists, key=lambda a: a[0])
        a = dists[0][1]
        b = dists[0][2]
        old = contour.copy()
        new = old[a:b]
        old1 = old[0:a]
        old2 = old[b:len(old)]
        old = np.concatenate((old1,old2))
        contours_new.append(old)
        contours_new.append(new)
    else:
        contours_new.append(contour)
```

I got rid of the numpy.delete function that did not work for me.